# Execute function within another function causes break

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript extension for a 3rd-party-tool, which I would like to extend with additional function. Function 1) builds the table, function 2) should resize the table. But when I try to execute function 2) `resizableGrid(html)`, the code stops working and neither function 2) nor the code after is working.

I've tried to break my code down:

```js
function() {
  var html = "<table id='dpi-simple-table'><thead><tr id='first-row'>";
  html += "<th>" + "..." + "</th>";
  html += "</tr></thead>";
  html += "<tbody></tr><td class=''>" + '...' + "</td></tr>";
  html += "</tbody></table>";
  $element.html(html);

  /* ########### function 2) ########### */
  function resizableGrid(e) {
    var t = e.getElementById("first-row")
      ...
  }
  /* ########### END function 2) ########### */

  var table = document.getElementById("dpi-simple-table");

  console.log(table);
  resizableGrid(html);
  console.log(html);
}
```

Comment: error refers to this `function() {` no function name was passed

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `html` variable which is string to the `resizableGrid` method which expects DOM element. `getElementById` is not a method of the string. You should pass `table` variable: `resizableGrid(table);`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the name of the function. I've added the name `foo`:

```js
function foo() { /* <-- here */
  var html = "<table id='dpi-simple-table'><thead><tr id='first-row'>";
  html += "<th>" + "..." + "</th>";
  html += "</tr></thead>";
  html += "<tbody></tr><td class=''>" + '...' + "</td></tr>";
  html += "</tbody></table>";
  //$element.html(html);

  /* ########### function 2) ########### */
  function resizableGrid(e) {
    console.log('function 2 is executed');
    var t = document.getElementById("first-row")
  }
  /* ########### END function 2) ########### */

  var table = document.getElementById("dpi-simple-table");

  console.log(table);
  resizableGrid(html);
  console.log(html);
}
foo();
```

Comment: You're right, but my function works thanks to `define(["jquery", "text!./dpi-simple.css"], function($, cssContent) {'use strict'; paint : function() { ... }`. I am stuck at function 2) which is not executed.

Comment: `function 2` is not executed because in your snipper `$element` is undefined. Otherwise if to comment it out it will be executed

Comment: If I put it down to the end of code (after `function 2`) `function 2` still isn't executed

Comment: @Jonas run my snippet, please. You will see it is executed